# Reduce React re-renders when executing multiple GraphQL mutations with Apollo React Client

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

**The Context**:
I am using the Apollo React Client in a fairly large React application, and leveraging the useQuery hook to fetch data for multiple React components.

**The Goal**:
I am looking for way to hold off the react re-renders until the final GraphQL mutation has completed, when executing multiple mutations in response to a single user-action

**The Problem**:
Several actions that can be performed in the application require multiple GraphQL mutations (and their corresponding cache updates) to be executed in response to one button click. This is resulting in a somewhat flickery/jerky rendering as the React components are re-rendering in response to each mutation.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Are you utilizing one `useMutation` hook or multiple ones?

Comment: multiple useMutation hooks in various nested components